# Solving simultaneous equations $2x = 1 - 3y$ and $3y^2 - x^2 = 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Someone please edit the question; also teach me to edit them! I'm new and I don't know how to do it!

1. $2x = 1 - 3y$
2. $3y^2 - x^2 = 2$

Solve these simultaneous equations.

Comment: What stops you substituting $x$ with $\displaystyle\frac{1-3y}2$ in the second equation?

Comment: nothing stops me, I did this and soon it gets complicated and I get confused!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$2x=1-3y$ ---(1)

$3y^2-x^2=2$ ---(2)

(1) gives $x=\frac{1-3y}{2}$ ---(3)

Substitute (3) into (2): $3y^2-\frac{1+9y^2-6y}{4}=2$

$12y^2-1-9y^2+6y-8=0$

$3y^2+6y-9=0$

$y^2+2y-3=0$

$(y+3)(y-1)=0$

Hence $y=-3$ and $x=5$, or $y=1$ and $x=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$3y^2-x^2=2\iff 12y^2-4x^2=8$$

$$\implies 12y^2-(1-3y)^2=8\iff 3y^2+6y-9=0\iff y^2+2y-3=0$$

Again,$$y^2+2y-3=y^2+(3-1)y-3=(y+3)(y-1)$$

Answer (score 0):

As @labbhattacharjee has pointed out correctly, using his method you get the solutions for $y$. Don't forget that you will have then to substitute those values in the original equation
$$
x=\frac{1-3y}{2}
$$
to get your $x$. To check yours, the solution is
$$
x=-1, y=1
$$
and
$$
x=5, y=-3
$$